# How to disable the checkbox click to make atleast one check box to be selected

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am new in angular2 ,I want disable the check box unchecking if there is only one check box is checked .my html page is look like this

```
    <div class="Columns-list-box pull-right">
        <a class="Columns-list" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample-check" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample-check">
            Columns <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse Columns-list-items" id="collapseExample-check">
            <ul class="sub-mnu" id="menu-check" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                <li >
                    <label><input #idDiv type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]= "productIdValue" (change)="mapItems($event)" name="id"  [checked]="defaultCheck"  >Id</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><input #skuDiv type="checkbox"  (change)="mapItems($event)" [(ngModel)]= "skuDivValue" checked    >SKU</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><input #shortnameDiv type="checkbox"  (change)="mapItems($event)"  [(ngModel)]= "ShortNameValue"  checked >Shortname</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><input #identifierDiv type="checkbox"  (change)="mapItems($event)"  [(ngModel)]="identifierDivValue" checked >Identifier</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><input #identifierTypeDiv type="checkbox" (change)="mapItems($event)" [(ngModel)]="identifierTypeValue" checked>Identifier Type</label>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

mapItems() {

```
if (this.productIdValue || this.skuDivValue || this.ShortNameValue || this.identifierDivValue || this.identifierTypeValue) {

}
else {
  this.defaultCheck = true;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried any code in js for disabling the checkbox?

Comment: What's your written js/angular code for it so far?